# Guzzle HTTP request error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle6, guzzle

I am trying to send my form data from one domain to another domain using API with Guzzle HTTP.
But when I am sending any file field that time it gives me error.

My First server Code

```
$inputs = $request->all();
$scan_2 = 'user_scan_2_' . $request->file('fileToUpload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$destination = base_path() . '/public/files/uploaded/user/temp/';
$request->file('fileToUpload')->move($destination, $scan_2);
$inputs['fileToUpload'] = $this->makeCurlFile($destination.'/'.$scan_2);
$response = Http::post('"http://msite.test/api/test', $inputs,$headers);
```

My Guzzle Code Over HTTP facade

```
public function send($method, $url, $data, $headers = ["Content-Type" => "application/json"]) {
    $method = strtoupper($method);
    $contentType = $headers['Content-Type'] ??  ($headers['content-type'] ?? '');
    $requestData['headers'] = $headers;

    if(in_array($method, ['GET', 'DELETE'])){
        $requestData['query'] = $data;

    }elseif(in_array($method, ['POST','PUT', 'PATCH'])){

        switch(strtolower($contentType)){
            case 'application/json':
                $requestData['json'] = $data;
                break;
            case 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
                $requestData['form_params'] = $data;
                break;
            case 'multipart/form-data':
                $requestData['multipart'] = $data;
                break;
            default:
                $requestData['body'] = $data;
                break;
        }
    }

        $response = $this->client->request($method, $url, $requestData);
    return $response;
}


public function post($url, $data = [], $headers = ["Content-Type" => "application/json"]) {
    return $this->send('post', $url, $data, $headers);
}
```

I am using content type as `multipart/form-data`
Now when I run my code that time got error

> Argument 2 passed to GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MultipartStream::addElement() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Comment: is `$headers` defined anywhere?

Comment: I'm guessing it could be that $data is a string but is required to be a string for `$requestData['form_params'] = $data;` ?

Comment: yes. @apokryfos

Comment: Check out http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart you don't seem to be formatting it the same way